# Textarea only resizes 1 area

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I'm having problems with my textareas. The problem is that i want to have multiple textarea's that need to be resized on page load. This works fine for one textarea, but when i insert 2 textarea's (or more) only the first one will work. So all the textarea's after the first one **do not** resize to their height.

my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body onload="callOnPageLoad()">
<script>
function callOnPageLoad(){
 document.getElementById("textareaEx").style.height="1px";
 document.getElementById("textareaEx").style.height=(25+document.getElementById("textareaEx").scrollHeight)+"px";
 }
</script>
<textarea onkeyup="callOnPageLoad()" id="textareaEx" style="overflow:hidden">Identify, formulate, research literature, and analyze user needs and taking them into account to solve complex information technology problems, reaching substantiated conclusions using fundamental principles of mathematics, computing fundamentals, technical concepts and practices in the core information technologies, and relevant domain disciplines.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: _but when i insert 2 textarea's..._ Post the code

Comment: You are probably using same id for both textarea, which will cause the issue.

Comment: @Diljohn5741 Do you have a suggestion on what i could do?

Comment: try getting the element by tag name then loop in each element then resize

Comment: @Quentin below have posted an answer. That will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Quentin said "An id must be unique on a page.

If you have multiple elements on a page, then getElementById will return the first one and error recovery will ignore the others."

here's a snippet using document.getElementsByClassName to iterate / access all the textArea elements

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body onload="callOnPageLoad()">
  <script>
    function callOnPageLoad() {
      var ta = document.getElementsByClassName("ta");

      for (i = 0; i < ta.length; i++) {

        ta[i].style.height = "1px";
        ta[i].style.height = (25 + ta[i].scrollHeight) + "px";
      }
      //  document.getElementById("textareaEx").style.height="1px";
      //  document.getElementById("textareaEx").style.height=(25+document.getElementById("textareaEx").scrollHeight)+"px";

    }
  </script>
  <textarea class="ta" onkeyup="callOnPageLoad()" id="textareaEx" style="overflow:hidden">Identify, formulate, research literature, and analyze user needs and taking them into account to solve complex information technology problems, reaching substantiated conclusions using fundamental principles of mathematics, computing fundamentals, technical concepts and practices in the core information technologies, and relevant domain disciplines.</textarea>

  <textarea class="ta" onkeyup="callOnPageLoad()" id="textareaEx1" style="overflow:hidden">Identify, formulate, research literature, and analyze user needs and taking them into account to solve complex information technology problems, reaching substantiated conclusions using fundamental principles of mathematics, computing fundamentals, technical concepts and practices in the core information technologies, and relevant domain disciplines.</textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

An `id` *must* be unique on a page.

If you have multiple elements on a page, then `getElementById` will return the first one and error recovery will ignore the others.

If you want to identify a group of elements, then you can use a `class` instead of an `id`.

You can get elements that are members of a class via `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`. These will return a Node List that you can loop over like an array to access each element in turn.